# JavaScript Paste from Clipboard not working

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to use Paste function as code below but it's not working. Only focus/selection methods are working.

```js
function actionPaste() {
  var pasteText = document.getElementById("myInput");
  pasteText.focus();
  pasteText.select();
  pasteText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999);
  document.execCommand("paste");
}
```

```html
<input id="myInput" type="text" />
<button onclick="actionPaste()">Paste</button>
```

Comment: Do you want the text being copied what are you writing into the input field or paste into  the input field which is copied already to clipboard?

Comment: @ShahnawazHossan Yes it's a input field with double responsibility. That generates a "token", also can be inputed a value to check if it's a valid token

Comment: @blex the function Paste coded in that question works! But on every click in my Paste Button the permission popup is executed... Can't open the popup just once?